# django custom action name change according to model name

Tags: python, django, django-models, custom-action

I have created a custom admin action. I am using that action in more than one listing page.

In my admin.py file

```
def custom_action(request, modelAdmin, queryset):
    #do something here
    return response

custom_action.short_description = 'My custom action for X'


class MyXAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      actions = [custom_action]

class MyYAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      actions = [custom_action]
```

In both of my X and Y listing page it appears "My custom action for x". Is there any way to change the "X" => "Y" for Y listing page.

OR

How can I achieve to rename the custom_action name for individual listing page in djagno without writing custom method for each model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MyXAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      actions = [custom_action]
      custom_action.short_description = 'My custom action for X'

class MyYAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      actions = [custom_action]
      custom_action.short_description = 'My custom action for Y'
```

Comment: It stays the newest shor_description. I mean for your code it will show 'My custom action for Y' for all listing page. It didn't work.